# Getting error 'Compile error in hidden module: CTDConn' when opening and closing Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-office

Whenever I am opening or closing MS Excel I get the following error

> Compile error in hidden module: CTDConn

I tried the suggestions listed in [this link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/307410/you-receive-a-compile-error-in-hidden-module-error-message-when-you-start-word-or-excel) but it didn't work.

- Pdfmaker.dot/Pdfmaker.xla is not present in my AppData
- I have McAfee

I don't get this error on other MS Office programs like Word or PowerPoint. I am using MS Office Professional Plus 2010.

How can I get rid of this error?

Comment: Take a look: https://community.saas.hpe.com/t5/Quality-Center-ALM-Practitioners/Compile-error-in-hidden-module-CTDServer/m-p/1069363#M10159

Comment: @duDE: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. It was because of ALM software. I uninstalled it and the error is gone.

Comment: Nice! Consider to write your solution down as an answer, you can accept it then. That will help other user to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [this link](https://community.saas.hpe.com/t5/Quality-Center-ALM-Practitioners/Compile-error-in-hidden-module-CTDServer/m-p/1069363#M10159) (thanks [duDE](https://superuser.com/users/192966/dude)) I discovered that this issue is because of ALM. I unistalled ALM and the error is gone.